# How to use .off('click') when do like $('.parent').on( 'click' , '.children');

Tags: jquery, click

When I have multiple divs like...

```
<div class="parent">
    <button class="children">click</button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <button class="children">click</button>
</div>
```

(Normally, I add this html by using jQuery)

I will my buttons will work only one time per one button

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
    alert('test');
    $(this).off('click','.children');
});
```

I have no idea how to `.off()` click event each button ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/AYwhL/

PS : jQuery 1.9+

PS : I dont want to cancel all button events

Comment: You have to call `.off` an the element you bound the handler to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `.off` on the original element:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
    alert('test');
    $(".parent").off('click','.children');
});
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/5EVc5/) updated Fiddle. But you could always use `.one` to achieve the same result?

```
$('.parent').one('click', '.children', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Nope, that will cancel all buttons

Comment: @l2aelba Nope, it won't because I've provided a selector as per the jQuery docs.

Comment: +1 The correct solution is using `one` other one will not work

Comment: Does `one()` support event delegation?

Comment: According to the docs: `.off( events [, selector ])`. Selector is defined as: "A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers". Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @billyonecan yes see the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) also in action http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZzDvA/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I never knew that, awesome :D

Comment: But does it work as expected? Does it run the handler once for each descendant or only once at all. *edit:* Ok, Arun's jsFiddle proofed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
    alert('test');
    $(this).parent().off('click');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/24HVF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use event delegation, then you cannot unbind the event handler for a specific element, since the handler is not bound to the element in the first place.

However, you can set a flag on each element to indicate whether it was processed or not:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
    if ($(this).data('clicked')) return;
    alert('test');
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

Apparently you can achieve the same with [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) though. It can also handle event delegation.

Comment: What about , @Anton's answer ?

Comment: That won't work as expected if there are multiple `.children` elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/ZzDvA/3/.

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest to accept Blade0rz answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186801/218196.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) like,

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
    alert('test');
    $(this).closest('.parent').off('click');// <-- to off all children click
});
```

Comment: I cannot imagine `$(this).off('click');` to work, since the event handler is not bound to that element.